# Trying to resize a text input. (Kivy, QPython, Android). But not sure how to write the code correctly

Tags: android, python, kivy

I want to resize the text input as it fills up half of the screen.

This code fills up [half of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPINR.jpg):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 

class MyApp(App): 
   def build(self): 
     self.box = BoxLayout() 
     self.label = Label(text="Hi there, Welcome.") 
     self.txt = TextInput(text="Hello World")
     self.box.add_widget(self.label) 
     self.box.add_widget(self.txt) 
     return self.box 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MyApp().run()
```

I googled some with the same issue and I saw this: [Python kivy - how to reduce height of TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283284/python-kivy-how-to-reduce-height-of-textinput)and) tried one from the answer:

Trying to resize it like this, but doesn't work, (not really sure how's the right way) Kivy launcher will close right after tapping it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 

class MyApp(App): 
   def build(self): 
     self.box = BoxLayout() 
     self.label = Label(text="Hi there, Welcome.") 
     self.txt = TextInput()
     TextInput:
         size_hint: (.2, None)
         height: 30 
         multiline: False 
         text: "hello world"
     self.box.add_widget(self.label) 
     self.box.add_widget(self.txt) 
     return self.box 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: That is kv language. You need to put it in a kv file or `Builder.load_string(kvstring)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using Python code

The following is the kv language converted into Python code.

```
 self.txt = TextInput(size_hint=(.2, None), height=30, multiline=False, text="hello world")
```

## Using Kivy Builder

The following solution illustrates using Kivy Builder to load the kv language.

### Snippets - main

```
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<TextInput>:
    size_hint: (.2, None)
    height: 30
    multiline: False
    text: "hello world"
""")
```

## Example

The following example contains both solution but one of it is commented out.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<TextInput>:
    size_hint: (.2, None)
    height: 30
    multiline: False
    text: "hello world"
""")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box = BoxLayout()
        self.label = Label(text="Hi there, Welcome.")
        # self.txt = TextInput(size_hint=(.2, None), height=30, multiline=False, text="hello world")
        self.txt = TextInput()
        self.box.add_widget(self.label)
        self.box.add_widget(self.txt)
        return self.box


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```